# Equation of a 3D curve shaped like a logarithmic spiral

Tags: geometry, surfaces

I'm not exactly certain of the mathematical description of this surface (if I were I wouldn't have a question), but I basically want to make a "3D spiral" which is basically a sine wave "wrapped" around a logarithmic spiral in a continuous sense.

The only real-life example I can think of something like this is if you had a blanket that you grabbed a point on and twisted, but I can describe it more effectively [with an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K13y.jpg). Imagine that image as a logarithmic, rather than archimedian spiral. (The equation that generated that image is $z=sin(\theta+r)$ down to scaling factors, but I can think of absolutely no way to incorporate a power without it being discontinuous near $\theta=2\pi\cong0$. The best result I've achieved is demonstrated in [this failed attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVEoA.png), the formula for which I seem to have lost but it was a hack anyway.)

Because I'm writing this as part of a computer program which is rendering an image from the output, I need to cover every point on a grid, so I can't use a parametric approach which covers points in its own order.

Comment: Your image $z = \sin(\theta + r)$ corresponds to the Archimedean spiral $\theta + r = 0$. So for the logarithmic spiral $\theta + \log r = 0$, try $z = \sin(\theta + \log r)$.

Comment: That worked beautifully, if you would care to post it as an actual answer, perhaps including an explanation, I'll accept it.